# Best way to share vim configuration between cygwin-vim and windows-gvim and launch it

Tags: windows, vim, configuration, cygwin

I am trying to setup my cygwin environment.
Since I am a vim user, I want to use it easily on cygwin and windows.

### Sharing vim configuration

**My first concern is to share the configuration (.vimrc/_vimrc and .vim/_vimfiles) between the two of them.**
Indeed, I am recently hosting my vim config on github and trying to get my plugins updated thru github too.

So I made some googling to find the best way to do it but I failed to find a 'good solution' (not easy to define though...).
Anyway, lots of people seems to agree on the fact that it is best to use windows-gvim rather than cygwin-gvim (I failed to use cygwin-gvim propably because of X issues but I didn't wanted to look further).
So first question : is it true?!

Then  I tried to find some solutions based on windows-gvim.
At the moment, I have linked the win env. in the cyg env.:

```
.vim -> /cygdrive/d/Program Files/Vim/vimfiles/
.vimrc -> /cygdrive/d/Program Files/Vim/_vimrc
```

But when I open gvim from cygwin it fails. I think that win-gvim can't read cygwin's simlinks.

I tried to link the vimfiles directory (so win side) but them win-gvim can't find anything too!
**What I don't understand here is why win-gvim launched from cygwin looks at the files from my cygwin home dir?!**

I read it is possible to declare a HOME variable in windows to help win-vim, but I fear it can have side effects...

That's it for the config the config...
**Does somebody has a solution?**

### Launching vim

Also, to launch gvim I use an alias to a function that translates cigpaths in winpaths:

```
winfilepath () {
  # Extract command
  cmd="$1"
  shift
  # Computes file paths
  allfiles=""
  if [[ ! -z "$@" ]]; then
    while read f
    do
      newpath=`cygpath -w $f`
      allfiles="$allfiles $newpath"
    done < <(echo "$@" )
  fi

  # Launch command
  echo "winfilepath: "$cmd $allfiles
  $cmd $allfiles
}

alias gvim="winfilepath gvim \"$@\""
alias gvimdiff="winfilepath gvimdiff \"$@\""

# Open Windows explorer with file
alias winopen="winfilepath \"explorer.exe /select,\" \"$@\""
```

**Is it a good pratice?**

Thank you for your help :)

Plouff

Comment: I like your alias to launch gvim. I use a slightly different method, as I was having trouble handling files with spaces in their paths. Do you have any problems with that?

Comment: Hi, unfortunatly that the issue I have with this launcher. I still need to debug this... Spacess are so annoying!!! What's your solution for spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I finally had time to fix this issue!
To find a ./_(g)vimrc, (g)vim first looks in the $HOME directory. If it can't find a _/.(g)vimrc in it then it looks in the $VIM directory.

Since cygwin sets the $HOME environment variable, my win-gvim was trying to open the simlink in my home directory.
So to load the right rc file, I need to set the $HOME variable correctly. I ended up with this new function:

```
#
# Compute windows file path and launch command in argument
#
winfilepath () {
  # Extract command
  cmd="$1"
  shift
  # Computes file paths
  allfiles=""
  if [[ ! -z "$@" ]]; then
    while read f
    do
      newpath=`cygpath -w "$f"`
      allfiles="$allfiles $newpath"
    done < <(echo "$@" )
  fi

  # Launch command
  echo "winfilepath: "$cmd $allfiles
  $cmd $allfiles
}

#######
# Launching VIM
#######
winvim () {
  # HOME env var management
  myhomebak=$HOME
  export HOME="/cygdrive/d/Program\ Files/Vim"
  # Extract command
  cmd="$1"
  shift
  winfilepath $cmd "$@"
  export HOME=$myhomebak
}

alias gvim="winvim gvim \"$@\""
alias gvimdiff="winvim gvimdiff \"$@\""
```

Combined with the solution of Bryan Ross, I can now share my config!
Thanks for your help.

Now I need to fix this white space issue......

Answer (score 11):

I keep my dotfiles in Dropbox. The folder is C:\Dropbox\dotfiles. In order to use them between windows and cygwin, here's what I do:

Cygwin side:

```
~ $ ln -s /cygdrive/c/Dropbox/dotfiles/.vimrc
~ $ ln -s /cygdrive/c/Dropbox/dotfiles/.gvimrc
~ $ ln -s /cygdrive/c/Dropbox/dotfiles/.vim
```

That takes care of vim in cygwin (both terminal vim and gtk gvim)

Windows side:

```
C:\Users\Bryan>mklink _vimrc C:\Dropbox\dotfiles\.vimrc
C:\Users\Bryan>mklink _gvimrc C:\Dropbox\dotfiles\.gvimrc
C:\Users\Bryan>mklink /D vimfiles C:\Dropbox\dotfiles\.vim
```

That takes care of windows vim (both commmand line vim and windows gvim)

This has been working for me successfully for about two years now.

Comment: It is still failing. I made links in the vim folder and in my win user folder but win-gvim complains about simlink... I don't understand the behavior of win-gvim. I think it is still trying to open the .vim* from the cygwin side! Maybe my win setup is different, I am using Win7...

Comment: I just edited my answer. There's a /D switch you need for the .vim folder link, so Windows knows it's a directory symbolic link instead of a file symbolic link

Comment: @Plouff Apparently you really do need to use the windows cmd prompt and `mklink` to make the windows links. If you use cygwin's `ln -s` to create the _vimrc and vimfiles links gvim will throw the symlink error when you start it.

Comment: @Matthew: Thanks for the update. I stop using cygwin at the moment. But I may need it again in a near future. I hope it will help me!

Answer (score 1):

I use [Homeshick](https://github.com/andsens/homeshick) to keep my dotfiles in GitHub, instead of using Dropbox like [@rossipedia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7058486/25507) does, so I prefer to make my Cygwin setups the "authoritative" version and let Windows gVim use those.

The [Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Single_config_file_for_Vim_on_Windows_with_Cygwin) explains how to do this.  Based on that, and updated for Homeshick, create a `%HOMEPATH%\_vimrc` file in Windows that contains the following:

```
set runtimepath+=c:/cygwin/home/username/.homesick/repos/dotfiles/home/.vim
source c:/cygwin/home/username/.homesick/repos/dotfiles/home/.vimrc
```

Or, more generically, and letting the repository's files take precedence over others in the runtime path:

```
let &runtimepath = $HOME . "/.homesick/repos/dotfiles/home/.vim," . &runtimepath
source $HOME/.homesick/repos/dotfiles/home/.vimrc
```